# Is there any etymological difference between 'category' and 'predicate' in Aristotle?

Tags: aristotle

My question is whether 'category' and 'predicate' (and 'predicable') come from the same Greek word 'κατηγορία' in Aristotle. If so, predication is ontological by nature, in Aristotle, rather than linguistic or logical.

Comment: See https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-categories/ "Finally, some scholars have synthesized the linguistic and extra-linguistic interpretations by interpreting Aristotle as classifying linguistic predicates in so far as they are related to the world in semantically significant ways." The etymology is the same but there is still a distinction to be made between the ontology and linguistics.

Comment: @Not_Here, thanks for the link. It would be nice if anybody could give me the Greek originals for those three words. So far, I have category = κατηγορία, predicables = κατηγορούμενα (according to Bochenski's Ancient Formal Logic). So predicable = ? and predicate = ?

Comment: Maybe useful: M.Loux, *Being, Categories, and Universal Reference in Aristolte*, in Leila Haaparanta & Heikki Koskinen (editors), [Categories of Being: Essays on Metaphysics and Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=yz8sko5zVyUC&pg=PA17) (2012).

Comment: Also useful specific parts of Christopher Shields (editor), [The Oxford Handbook of Aristotle](https://books.google.it/books?id=vTVsrl0mnH4C&pg=PR7) (2012).

Comment: @Mauro, the Handbook is useful, has what I need. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please explain why you think "κατηγορία" and "predicate" being etymologically related means "predication is ontological by nature, in Aristotle, rather than linguistic or logical"?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Hi. Your Aristotle Glossary link leads to wiki article on beth definability.

Comment: @Geremai, my understanding is that Aristotle's categories are ontological categories. Then in the course of time, Aristotle came to think in 'ontolinguistic' terms, ie, to talk about the world properly. By the time of writing his syllogistics, it turns out to be a logical language, but in fact, the syllogistics, again as I understand it, is in fact a language  which helps us to talk about the world 'properly'. Now, in the syllogistics, the system is all about proper predication (categorization), but the underlying objective is really about talking about the real world properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will add here the most common usages of the term κατηγορώ.

An accuser in a court is a κατήγορος.

A sentence is in general a κατηγόρημα applied via the verb to the subject.

"Socrates is sleeping" Socrates the subject is called that he is sleeping, his being is categorized "accused- called" with the accidental of sleep.

"Socrates is beautiful" Beautiful is called in Greek grammar *κατηγορούμενο*. (an adjective called on the subject)

The "*κατηγορίες*", genres, species, *αυτό το φυτό ανήκει στην κατηγορία των οπωροφόρων*, this plant belongs to the taxonomy (category) of orchards.

Ταξινομία means to puts something in its τάξη, i.e. order. Category means to have called something as different and distinguishable from others. To be able to call something on its own, to accuse it, means to differentiate it.

κατά + αγορεύω = "for this" "I talk in public" , plead

a. η απόδοση μομφής σε κάποιον, καταγγελία = complaint, denunciation

b. η ομάδα στην οποία ανήκει ένα είδος, το σύνολο ομοίων πραγμάτων ή ιδεών

ομάδα, τάξη, σύνολο/ group, taxis- order, aggregation, summation

Comment: your explanation has clarified a lot. Thanks.

Comment: I reread your answer and compared what you said with the Aristotelian texts, it really makes a lot more sense to what the ancient Greeks were saying in the agora. Great stuff. Thanks.

Comment: very interesting. sounds a lot like "claim", and a claim must be made _by_ somebody.

Answer (score 0):

Etymologically, they are very similar. [κατηγορία](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=%CE%BA%CE%B1%CF%84%CE%B7%CE%B3%CE%BF%CF%81%CE%AF%CE%B1&la=greek#lexicon) means, [according to the *OED*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/28877):

> accusation, assertion, predication, abstract noun < *κατήγορος* accuser

"Predicate" comes from *pre-* (before) + *[dicare](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=dicare&la=la#lexicon)* (to say, assert).